# To create a view in a linked SQL Server 2005 database with some data types transformations

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

There are two linked SQL Server 2005 machines, server A with a lot of data and empty base on sever B.

Our user does not have a permission to create views on A, but have this ability on server B.
We checked out a possibility to make selects @B to A, and it's ok, there's a connection.

Please, prompt us on how to make a view @B, that just copies a table with transforming some fields' data types from binary to nvarchar.

Comment: The ability to create views doesn't mean there's the ability to insert data...

Answer (score 1):

You say that the servers are already linked servers, and you've proven the ability to run a `SELECT` on Server B that queries Server A.  All you have to do at that point is prefix the `SELECT` with a `CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyView]` statement and you've created a view for that query.

To convert to/from nvarchar & binary, use the `CONVERT` function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28SQL.90%29.aspx

If you want to copy the data to a table on Server B, write an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM [ServerA].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[SourceTable]`